# Optimal design for improved performance of a simulation code

Tags: design, object-oriented, c++, performance

I'm writing a code for the [Discrete Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_element_method) where I have balls (spheres) and walls (planes) interacting with each other.

Those simulations are run for billions of time steps, so performance here really matters. Right now, I'm considering different designs and am not sure which one is the best.

I'll try to explain them and my doubts.

---

#### Alternative 1 - probably the best for maintainability

One class for the balls:

```
class Balls:
   /* contains:
  geometry
  forces
  positions
  velocities
  etc.
  of balls */
```

One class for the walls:

```
class Walls:
   /* contains:
  geometry
  forces
  positions
  velocities
  etc.
  of Walls */
```

An assembly which also contains the solver:

```
class Assembly:
  /* contains:
  balls object
  walls object
  other parameters for the assembly

  Solver:
   method to compute interactions balls-balls and walls-balls
   method to advance time (time integration)
```

The question here is, how do I get the less overhead? The solver has to access almost all attributes of the other two classes. Shall I write getters or declare the `World` class as `friend` of the other two?

#### Alternative 2 - could become a mess

A solver class:

```
class Solver:
  /* Contains:
  some solver related parameters (e.g., step size)
  Two methods:
   method to compute interactions balls-balls and walls-balls
   method to advance time (time integration)
```

An assembly class which contains all the definitions of the walls and balls

```
class Assembly:
  /* contains basically all attributes of the two 
  classes Walls and Balls shown in the alternative 1 and 
  a method which calls the two methods of the class solver
  by passing the balls/walls attributes by reference */
```

Also here, is it then better to pass the attributes by reference, to declare the `World` class as `friend` of the `Solver` class, or to use getters?

#### Alternative 3 - the less maintainable

Combine everything in just one class (not really considered).

---

Finally, what's the design that reduce the most the overhead? Can you suggest any better design than mine?

---

EDIT: to be noted is that in the classes `Balls` and `Walls` I would store everything in one object. So an object `Balls balls` will contain for example (if the whole assembly only contains 2 balls):

```
vector<Eigen::Vector3d> ball_positions = {Eigen::Vector3d(x1,y1,z1),
                                          Eigen::Vector3d(x2,y2,z2)}
vector<double> ball_radii = {r1,r2}
```

Comment: First idea to come to mind: Ball and Walls as structs instead of classes, stored contiguously so they stay in cache. Also, can you do computations in GPU (pass data as a uniform array or texture, and write a fragment or compute shader, for example)? You could aks people on [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), that sounds right up their alley.

Comment: I found an open source C++ project that could be of use: [cryphous](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cryphous/). Description: "Fluid simulation engine and fluid rendering engine for real-time applications." [Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdyV7IyT6iE).

Comment: You may also be interested in: [NVIDIA CUDA realtime particles demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqduA7myZok).

Comment: Access patterns are important for performance.  Arrays of integers can do better than random access of objects, especially if arrays' content can be arranged for sequential access.

Comment: @Theraot thanks for your interesting comments. About the 1st: I'm not sur that I understood correctly what you mean. But I also I think I haven't explained enough my idea. The class `Balls` would contain stl vectors containing the positions, the radii etc. of all balls. The only data that is touched for all balls in an O(n^2) manner are radii and positions, so I thought this approach may be faster. But I could indeed be wrong..
About gamedev, you're actually right. But I think either I move this question or I go against SExchange guidlines if I post twice the same question

Comment: @Theraot about the second and third: Thanks! I'll have a look into it. There are actually some other open source projects as well which are however almost too broadly formulated (too generalized) at the cost of the performance. But they are for sure a good inspiration.

Comment: @ErikEidt I updated the question to add a better explanation of what I had in my mind. I think that's what you meant, right?

Comment: Yes, you should not crosspost. However, first thing gamedev people will ask is what have you tried, thus, it would not be exactly the same question. Second thing is that they will tell you that you do not need to check every ball against every ball for collisions, have a search: [optimize collision detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=optimize+collision+detection) (you only need to check balls that are close enough). If you really need forces applied from all balls, compute use a vector field from them (O(n), well O(n*m), m is resolution), then use it to update them (O(n)).

Comment: * https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/what-is-data-oriented-game-engine-design--cms-21052 
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design

Comment: Are you asking this for an exercise in writing such an algorithm? Because if it's "for real", it seems from the Wikipedia article that DEM is an active field of research. So you should be able to find optimised algorithms and data structures published for your use case. I don't think that usually you would be able to come up with something better than the researchers. If it's not that critical and you'd rather just implement something quickly, just prototype your preferred (maintainable) way and benchmark it.

Comment: Yes, that's "for real" and yes I'm aware of the publications. You find a lot of material especially about the contact detection algorithm. I asked here about the design because I still believe many available codes (open source and not) sometimes have to give priority to a general application (so that you can model whatever you want) in spite of performance. I instead want to write a code which is pretty much tailored to my specific problem and get the maximum performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is at stake, the only way to know for sure is to benchmark.

Alternative 1 has the advantage of being easily extensible, if you would use polymorphism:

```
class SimulationObject {
    // common properties 
    // virtual functions for anything that changes according to real objects
}; 

class Sphere: public SimulationObject {
    ...
};
class Wall: public SimulationObject {
    ...
};
```

[Virtual functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/) have a minor overhead since there is an extra indirection (not a big deal for modern CPUs).  But this can be neglected compared to additional conditional statement needed to vary behavior depending on type.

You may use [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++) to cope very effectively with the combinatorial explosion of possible interactions between different kind of objects.  Today it's only spheres and balls;  but what when you have spheres, cubes and walls?  where spheres could bounce on other spheres or cubes before hitting the wall?

The other alternatives do not really seem sustainable to me. And I'm not sure that the performance would be higher, if you have to go through long chains of conditionals to figure out what specific case in which specific interaction/combination.

Comment: Thanks. You're indeed right. Thanks for your interesting inputs. I think double dispatch is more useful in event driven simulations. In my case I have (unfortunately) a situation where I have to check contact of every balls with every other simulation object, so I have O(n^2) time complexity (the only solution to reduce the cost a little bit is to use so called [Verlet Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_list))

Comment: @David thanks for the interesting feedback.  If I understand this data structure,  it keeps a reduced list of objects in range.  I could imagine that if you have more than 2 kind of objects,  double dispatch could still help on the reduced set.

Comment: still a last question before accepting your answer. Would you then use getters to access attributes from the solver, or declare the `Assembly` class as friend?

Comment: @David I'd use getters and setters, since those enable the polymorphism and will facilitate maintenance.  Having assembly as friend is in reality a disguised variant of alternative 3.